# Existing Zend 1.10 framework project incorporating Symfony 2 framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've got an existing project using zend 1.10 framework.  I'm not fond of zend but I can't sell the idea of converting over to symfony, I'd like to just incorporate symfony 2 into the code base and at least use it for new code (doctrine, forms and twig templates at least, even if I'm stuck with zends' MVC structure).

Not sure how to go about setting this up.  I see lots of mention of using Zend classes in Symfony but not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Twig](http://www.rmauger.co.uk/2011/05/using-twig-with-zend-framework/) and [Doctrine](http://www.spiffyjr.me/2010/11/17/zend-framework-1-11-doctrine-2-lets-play-nice-part-1/) with ZF, so that's no problem. However the forms component is not on the list of [stand alone components for Symfony 2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/index.html) so implementing Symfony 2 forms in ZF 1.10 might be tricky.

Good Luck.

Comment: I actually wanted to pull in all of symfony and start using it on new code.  So, if I'm making a new screen or refactoring an existing one I could use symfony on it, while letting the rest of the zend based code still run.